# Dim varName as int64 in Go?

Tags: go

How do I write the equivalent of `Dim varName as int64 = value` in Go?

Whenever I find myself needing to declare a variable in Go I google a lot until I find the correct syntax.

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go.

Comment: Welcome To Go, please stop everything that you are doing and take the [tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks zero research or understanding the very basics of the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a [variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) (can be used inside functions and at the top level to create global variables):

```
var i int64 = value
```

If `value` is a typed `int64` value, you may omit the type which will be inferred:

```
var i2 = value // type is inferred
```

[Short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) (may only appear inside function bodies):

```
i3 := value // type is inferred
```

**Notes:**

Both with the variable declaration (without type) and with short variable declaration care must be taken if you use a value with different type - or an untyped constant. In these cases explicit [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) may be required in order for the new variable to get the proper `int64` type!

```
var i4 = 4        // Wrong! i4 will be of type int
var i5 = int64(4) // Good! i5 will be of type int64
var i6 int64 = 4  // Also good: explicitly provided type
i7 := 4           // Wrong! i4 will be of type int
i8 := int64(4)    // Good! i5 will be of type int64
```